# Setting the PATH variable for a new command in Perl shows error: Command not found

Tags: path, command, environment-variables

I am writing a Perl script to add a new command.
For this:

1. I have used the set env `PATH` command and added the directory containing the script (name same as the command name).
2. I have also made the script executable.

I have tried doing this both:

1. Explicitly: On the terminal using `setenv PATH $PATH":home/user/trial_dir"`

Here it says: `Command not found` when I type the command name.

2. Script: `export PATH = "home/user/trial_dir".":".$PATH;`

Here it says:

```
Can't locate object method "export" via package "PATH"
(perhaps you forgot to load "PATH"?)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your shell? `setenv` is csh syntax, but the error message looks like a Bash error message.  Anyway, the proper syntax for `csh` and `tcsh` is

```
setenv PATH $PATH":/home/user/trial_dir"
```

Note in particular the added slash before `home`. Relative paths in `PATH` generally make no sense.  I am guessing this is the reason your first attempt failed.

Additionally, if the script file has DOS CRLF [line terminators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) (in particular, on the [shebang line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29)), that would produce the same symptoms -- the message is `debug: command not found` even though the `debug` script was actually found, but the command on the shebang line was not found. (You would notice that `which debug` indicates that `tcsh` actually finds the script in this case.)

The second attempt is wrong because *(a)* you cannot have spaces around the assignment in `sh` syntax, and *(b)* the error message looks like you somehow passed this command to Perl instead of to the shell (what do you mean by "Script:"?)

The correct syntax at the Bash (or generally *`sh` excepting *`csh`) prompt would be

```
export PATH="/home/user/trial_dir":$PATH
```

(I added a leading `/` before `home` here too) but since you say you are using `tcsh` I am only mentioning this for completeness.  This is not a valid Perl command.

While there is nothing wrong with this approach, a common practice is to put your script (or a symlink to it) in `$HOME/bin` and just once and for all make sure `$HOME/bin` is in your `PATH` (this is already the default on some Linux distros).

Whether or not your added directory should come before or after the previous `PATH` is largely a matter of taste.  Modern shells generally use hashing, so the command will only be looked up the first time you try to use it, and after that, the shell remembers where it can be found.  If you often mistype commands, maybe try to keep your `PATH` as limited as possible. :-)  If your command needs to shadow a system command, definitely put the new directory in front of the system `PATH`.

Comment: Thanks.My shell is tcsh.By script I meant that first I run a PERL script that sets the PATH using the command export.I tried the setenv command in the script earlier.It said command not found so I used export which is not working even after removing spaces.Actually I dont have permission to add this to the $home/bin directory.                                                                       However I am not able to understand why the first approach doesn't work.

Comment: `export` is a `sh` command, not a Perl command.  Perl would be `$env{"PATH"} .= ":/home/user/trial_dir"`.

Comment: Of course you have access to `$HOME/bin`; everything in your home directory is (or definitely should be) completely under your control.

Comment: "Perl" is not an acronym and should not be uppercased.

Comment: Thanks a ton.I used a shell script now in place of the PERL script.So now the setenv command works and the path is updated.But still I can't figure out why even after adding the file to the directory and running chmod +x filename, it shows command not found.Any help on this one?

Comment: I'll say it again: "Perl" is not an acronym. It's "Perl", not "PERL".

Comment: What is the precise file name, and how do you try to run it?  Maybe try the `rehash` command, even though I don't think it's necessary here.

Comment: Ok got that "Perl" :) . I added /home/user/trial_dir to the path variable where my script called "debug" is present. Now after making it executable I change to the /home/user directory and run debug on the terminal.It says:Command not found

Comment: Works for me.  http://pastebin.com/uXNm13VS <- Can you reproduce this on your system?

Comment: Notice I had to change the quoting in the answer relative to what I posted earlier. I have been mercifully forgetting the quirks of `tcsh`.

Comment: The debug file you made is a Perl script or tsch shell script?I tried both but still it gives the same error.

Comment: Like the shebang indicates, it's a Bourne shell script.  This should not matter at all as far as having `tcsh` find it and execute it.  Change `/bin/sh` to (the correct local equivalent of) `/usr/bin/env perl` or `/bin/tcsh` respectively for Perl or tcsh.

Comment: If you have DOS line feeds in the script file, that would produce the symptoms you describe.  See http://pastebin.com/1jXgJtjd for a demonstration and a fix.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! Had a doubt though.As I see \r\n is to be used for windows and \n for Unix.I am using a Virtual box unix on windows.For now I have removed any \n linefeeds and it wokrs fine .So why did these \n pose a problem .Is the virtaul box also treated as a windows system.No right?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  If you have `/bin/tcsh\r\n` on the shebang line, then the Linux kernel will look for `/bin/tcsh\r` which is not an existing file. The operating system running inside Virtualbox is completely independent from the host operating system for the purposes of this discussion.

Comment: And so the incorrect character which needs to be removed is `\r` (carriage return) not  `\n` (line feed).